# Symfony parameters Routes (Easy to answer)

Tags: symfony, redirect, parameters, routes

I try to pass my user id in parameter because I wanted to use it in an other function to link them but don't know why that don't work (I think that I do a mistake and will be easy to answer thx :)

```
return $this->redirect('/profile/new/', array(
            'id' => $user->getId(),
        ));
```

My receiver :

```
/**
 * Creates a new profile entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{id}", name="profile_new")
 */
public function newProfileAction(Request $request)
{
```

when I do `/profile/new/8` for example it works! But when I click in the button submit that don't redirect with the id ... (of course the routes are good and when I do - it works :

```
return $this->redirect('/profile/new');
```

my receiver (when it works) :

```
/**
 * Creates a new profile entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="profile_new")
 */
public function newProfileAction(Request $request)
{
```

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: what do you need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $this->redirectToRoute('ROUTENAME',[PARAMETERS]) means:

```
$this->redirectToRoute('profile_new',['id'=>$ID])
```

If you use $this->redirect('URL') you have to parse the URL so you need to "/profile/new/ID"

Comment: thx so mutch :) so what is the difference between /{id} and /ID ?

Comment: @LuisRosario /ID is a fixed page and /{id} is a dynamic page with a variable you give with.

Comment: so if i want to pass all the user and modify a variable in the other function for user how can i do ?

Comment: if i want to do in profile function : $user->setIdProfile($profile->getId());

Comment: in the option with the url you have to generate the url string by your self. with the toRoute option symfony will generate the real url for you. I hardly recommend not to generate the url by your self, let symfony do it for you!

Comment: Ok thx you so mutch ! But how can i use the id in the function profile now ? (for exemple if i want to set a $id with the value that i reveive) @fucethebads  ?

Comment: you should add $id in the definition of the function:
   public function newProfileAction($id, Request $request)